# Name it Dm6 or Bdim?

Tags: theory, harmony, chord-theory

I was trying to figure out what chord some melody is based on , and the problem is I can't name it.
It is like **Dm6** without 5th.
And also it could be **Bdim**.
It consists of D,B,F

And the note D is on bass part.
Key is in Am.
Prior bar is based on A chord.
[image]

Comment: I see you decided to unaccept my answer. Please let me know if there's an improvement or change you'd like made.

Answer (score 13):

Based on the excerpt shown, I would actually argue for another understanding: Dm7.

Since the stem-down D and F are held throughout the entire measure, we can assume they're chord tones unless other information suggests otherwise.

Now we have to determine which of the stem-up notes—C, B, and A—are chord tones. In order to do this, we often privilege two things: metrical placement and note length (what we call an "agogic accent").

In terms of metrical placement, we privilege notes that appear *on* the beat as opposed to off the beat. This logic suggests that the C and A would be chord tones, but not the B.

And the agogic accent suggests the same: B, being the shortest note in the entire measure, is most likely a non-chord tone.

With all of this in mind, we have the dotted-half D and F combined with the upper-voice A and C to create a Dm7 chord.

There are other readings, but this would be my preferred one.

Comment: Yes, and even simpler than that: you’d be hard pushed to argue anything other than 1 chord per bar here.

Answer (score 6):

Certainly not B anything! The B note is short, not on a strong part of the bar, therefore is a passing note. That leaves D, F and A, with a C note left over from the previous bar. Making a pretty sure Dm7. With D as the lowest note, that's preferrable to the only other contender - F6.

Comment: the note length and position do not define or restrict its function. If the chord on beat 2 was Am with a in the melody and c in the bass, the b would indeed be part of the chord (the resolution of the suspended c).

Answer (score 4):

In the most strict analysis, there are two chords in the measure: both Bdim and Dmin.

The initial C is a suspension from the previous measure. It resolves down to the B, forming a brief Bdim chord that immediately proceeds to Dmin. The following C is an anticipation, leading to the Amin in the next measure.

Although Bdim is "required" analytically, I would consider it as a passing chord, being so brief, and would think of the measure as simply being Dmin.

All in all, the three measures show what is called a "tonic expansion": i-(ii)-iv-i.

---

**Addendum**

> no b in the chord. This is not 19c harmony, **the c is not a dissonance that needs to resolve**. Laitz et al not relevant for this type of harmony. Am and Dm7. (emphasis mine)

This comment from @DamianleGassick should be taken to heart. The music in question was not written with adherence to common-practice tonality / functional harmony in mind. (I should say, "presumably not written..." as a hedge, as I'm ot familiar with the piece.) While I stand by the analysis of how the two measures in the OP function, it should always be kept in mind that in a great deal of contemporary music -- jazz and pop, especially -- chordal sevenths are not considered dissonant and are not intended or expected to operate as they would according to the strictures of (classical) functional analysis.

Comment: Since that C note is still present in the bar concerned, it will be part of the harmony in that bar. Hardly a suspension - C belongs to that previous bar as a harmony note.

Comment: @Tim I don't follow. C being "still present" is the definition of a suspension.

Comment: I didn't consider the C as a suspension, but perhaps I'm too strict with my definition. In my usage, a suspension must resolve down by step to a chord tone. Thus, in order for the C to be a suspension, the succeeding B *must* be a chord tone.

Comment: @Richard Good point. Checking....

Comment: @Aaron - since the C note was present at the beginning of the bar, and it actually fitted with the rest of the harmony at that point, I don't consider it to be a suspension. I've been wrong before!

Comment: The OP is nearly identical to Laitz, *The Complete Musician", p. 310, example 1.3.11. In that case, the B is considered the note or resolution as it is consonant with the bass. By that example, there would be two chords in the measure: a brief Bdim following by Dmin.

Comment: @Richard See edit and previous comment. The B is the resolution, forming part of a (brief) Bdim.

Comment: @Aaron Fair enough. For me personally, I'm always hesitant to give such a quick sixteenth note status as a chord tone. There's also the issue that ii relatively rarely moves to IV, but as I said at the end of my answer, there are multiple readings for this. What's the example you cited? (My Laitz version is different than yours.)

Comment: @Richard Regarding the Laitz example: 1) 13.11, not 1.3.11; 2) See here: [Additional discussion on “Name it Dm6 or Bdim?”](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3635/additional-discussion-on-name-it-dm6-or-bdim).

Comment: no b in the chord. This is not 19c harmony, the c is not a dissonance that needs to resolve. Laitz et al not relevant for this type of harmony. Am and Dm7.

Comment: If you're going to count the C on the third beat of bar 2 an anticipation then you should also count the C on the third beat of bar 1 as one. This supports the other two answers: a Dm7 chord. B is a passing note, the important notes are A and C.

Comment: @PiedPiper My analysis doesn't include a Dm7 chord. In that analysis, the Cs are neither suspensions nor anticipations; they're common tones. In my analysis both Cs are non-harmonic tones within bar 2.